# Blur behind transparent WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I am trying to create a WPF application with a semi transparent border-less window that blurs the background behind it.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried to use **[DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow)** which works only on windows Vista/7.

I am trying to find a solution that will work on Windows 7, 8 and 10.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work on Windows 8?  [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969527(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to imply DWM is always **on** on Windows 8

Comment: MS removed this functionality from win 8

Comment: you can still use DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow in Windows 8, however the behaviour is not as expected, it doesn't blur behind the app it just uses a solid fill based on whatever your windows colour scheme is

Comment: That's because MS removed the functionality, as I stated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For anyone interested, I have found a solution for Windows 10. It looks as though it isn't possible on Windows 8 though; as David Heffernan mentioned, `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` was removed from Windows 8. However, Microsoft re-introduced a solution for achieving this effect in Windows 10.

- Windows 10: [Solution using
  SetWindowCompositionAttribute](https://web.archive.org/web/20170701081532/http://withinrafael.com/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/)
- Windows 8: No solution
- Windows 7: you can continue to use `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`

Comment: Link now dead :/ would be handy to place snippets of the code at the time as least SO stays around

Comment: Link to the Github Repo: https://github.com/riverar/sample-win10-aeroglass

Answer (score 4):

I hope I am not late to the party. You can use the SetWindowCompositionAttribute, but you are then forced to set the WindowStyle to "None" and implement your own native Window funtionality and handles. Also inheriting from a custom control is quite complicated. However, long story short. There's BlurryControls.

You can find it via **NuGet** by browsing for "BlurryControls" or check out the code yourself on **[GitHub](https://github.com/ConfusedHorse/BlurryControls)**. Eitherway, I hope this is helpful.

On GitHub you will also find a sample application.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 8**

As much as a dead end that'd better be completely forgotten, we might need to make sure our programs behave consistently across versions. If there is no need for a dynamic background and especially if the window is relatively small (a prime candidate would be a message box or similar over our own application window), the solution of capturing the screen behind the window and blurring it manually might work. In the `Loaded` event handler:

```
var screen = window.Owner.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point((window.Owner.ActualWidth - window.ActualWidth) / 2, (window.Owner.ActualHeight - window.ActualHeight) / 2));
var rect = new Rectangle((int)screen.X, (int)screen.Y, (int)window.ActualWidth, (int)window.ActualHeight);
var bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
  graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, rect.Size);
border.Background = new ImageBrush(ApplyGaussianBlur(bitmap.ToBitmapImage())) {
  TileMode = TileMode.None,
  Stretch = Stretch.None,
  AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center,
  AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center,
};
```

where `border` is an outermost `Border`, normally left completely empty, only used on Windows 8.

The helper function is the usual bitmap conversion:

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapImage(this System.Drawing.Bitmap image) {
  var hBitmap = image.GetHbitmap();
  var bitmap = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
  DeleteObject(hBitmap);
  return bitmap;
}
```

`ApplyGaussianBlur()` is best solved with a direct bitmap manipulation package like `WriteableBitmapEx`, with the necessary [modifications.](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/discussions/236374)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft removed glass effects starting from Windows 8. That explains why the blur effect that you are expecting is not observed on Windows 8 and later. You will have to learn to live without it on those operating systems.

Comment: I understand that the glass effect has been removed in windows 8, there must still be a way of achieving this effect, I have seen other programs do it for example [Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/).

Comment: @Tom: [This](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/images/0730/Start10_texturedbackground.png) doesn't look like a genuine Aero glass effect. From the looks it appears as though the application took a screenshot of the background and multiplied it onto its own background texture.

Comment: @IInspectable: That's what I thought at first, however I ran a video behind it and you could see it moving, I tried the approach you mentioned, by taking a screenshot and adding it to the background and applying a blur effect, it does work, its just not ideal. and if the desktop changes while the window is open then the illusion is ruined.

Comment: @Tom: I just installed Windows 10, and you are right: The Gaussian Blur is back for several UI elements (Start menu, clock/calendar, Action Center, etc.).