# How to make frosted glass effect in Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app

So, how to make such effect using C# & XAML?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Zhc.gif]

Comment: Have you tried someting so far? Some code or anything that you've tried to do, but didn't work?

Comment: I was looking for something like this on the Internet, but there are examples that blur the image , but do not overlap , but they are not relevant to Windows 10 , so I do not even know where to start. And to know the people help me , I wrote here , but not for you to write a response to the contempt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blur behind transparent WPF window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778017/blur-behind-transparent-wpf-window)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been trying to create something like this ever since iOS 7 introduced the frosted glass. Now thanks to Win2D, it's a lot simpler to create similar effects  in WinRT.

First, you will need to get the **Win2D.uwp** package from NuGet.

The idea is to create a `GaussianBlurEffect` based on the image source and put it on top of another *white* colored mask to mimic the frosted glass look.

To get the `GaussianBlurEffect` ready, you will need to create a xaml control `CanvasControl` from the Win2D library. So the UI structure is something like this -

```
<Grid x:Name="ImagePanel2" Width="356" Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Image x:Name="Image2" Source="Assets/Food.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <Grid x:Name="Overlay" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationStarted="Overlay_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="Overlay_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="Overlay_ManipulationCompleted" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry x:Name="Clip" Rect="0, 0, 356, 200" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Rectangle x:Name="WhiteMask" Fill="White" />
        <Xaml:CanvasControl x:Name="Canvas" CreateResources="Canvas_CreateResources" Draw="Canvas_Draw" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Frosted Glass" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF595959" Margin="12,12,0,0" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="26.667" FontStyle="Italic" TextLineBounds="Tight" />
</Grid>
```

Note I've created a `Clip` for the `Overlay` element, 'cause I need to reduce the `Rect`'s third parameter (i.e. *the Width*) while I am panning it to the left to make an illusion that the `Overlay` is sliding along with my finger.

The code behind is quite straight forward -

```
void Canvas_CreateResources(CanvasControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
{
    args.TrackAsyncAction(CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
}

async Task CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender)
{
    // give it a little bit delay to ensure the image is load, ideally you want to Image.ImageOpened event instead
    await Task.Delay(200);

    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        // get the stream from the background image
        var target = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await target.RenderAsync(this.Image2);

        var pixelBuffer = await target.GetPixelsAsync();
        var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)target.PixelWidth, (uint)target.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        stream.Seek(0);

        // load the stream into our bitmap
        _bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, stream);
    }
}

void Canvas_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    using (var session = args.DrawingSession)
    {
        var blur = new GaussianBlurEffect
        {
            BlurAmount = 50.0f, // increase this to make it more blurry or vise versa.
            //Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced, // default value
            //BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Soft // default value
            Source = _bitmap
        };

        session.DrawImage(blur, new Rect(0, 0, sender.ActualWidth, sender.ActualHeight),
            new Rect(0, 0, _bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width, _bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height), 0.9f);
    }
}

void Overlay_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // reset the inital with of the Rect
    _x = (float)this.ImagePanel2.ActualWidth;
}

void Overlay_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the movement on X axis
    _x += (float)e.Delta.Translation.X;

    // keep the pan within the bountry
    if (_x > this.ImagePanel2.ActualWidth || _x < 0) return;

    // we clip the overlay to reveal the actual image underneath
    this.Clip.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, _x, this.ImagePanel2.ActualHeight);
}

void Overlay_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // reset the clip to show the full overlay
    this.Clip.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, this.ImagePanel2.ActualWidth, this.ImagePanel2.ActualHeight);
}
```

You can further adjust the `BlurAmount` property as well as the opacity figure (`0.9f`) to get youself the exact effect you want.

Also to note that there might be another (*better?*) way to do this in the future. If the [new Composition API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.composition) does support the `GaussianBlurEffect` in a future release, I will update the answer.

You can find the current working sample from this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/EffectsAndAnimationsWinComposition). And I've attached an image here to showcase how it looks like. :)

[image]

Comment: Oh, nice decision, thank you, but it's half of what I needed. So  can there be any option with dynamic content? So, we have mainpage and dynamic frames there, like here: `<Grid><SplitView><SplitView.Pane><Grid>overlay code, content</SplitView.Pane><Frame x:Name="dyn cont" /></SplitView></Grid> ` Just now it works for background image.

Comment: As I understood , it all depends of the image, which is then: `_bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "here");` So, can we send screen of current frame? Or is there another method?

Comment: @SnakeAce, `LoadAsync` also takes `IRandomAccessStream`. So you could use `RenderTargetBitmap` to get the bitmap from the any `UIElement` on the UI, and then convert it into `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`. See my updated answer.

Comment: See how to apply a more advanced blur [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699256/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-in-windows-10-creators-update/43972370#43972370).

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the Win2D classes and in there for the Canvas Effects - there is a GaussianBlurEffect that might be helpful. Here's the reference:
http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/N_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects.htm
and for the GaussianBlurEffect:
http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_GaussianBlurEffect.htm
including some C# code samples.

Addition: if you want to know how to use win2D, I just found a handy tutorial (which I am following myself right now :)) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/09/05/win2d.aspx

Comment: Haven't used the Win2D classes so can't say directly. But was wondering weather or not the method of using SetWindowCompositionAttribute might be better or worse from a performance standpoint? I know it uses Interop which might be a vote towards Win2D, but also seems very... Native, so to say :) (as you might hear, I haven't tested it myself, just know about it, if you haven't tested it yourself I'll experiment with it tomorrow and post my findings here) Example: http://withinrafael.com/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/ (sorry about the "In your face"-flag)